# Node.js multiple middleware export pattern

Tags: node.js, express, web

I use Nodejs, Expressjs and
I dont understand how exactly work next() in middleware

## middleware/myMiddleware.js

```
const { Router } = require('express');
const router = Router();

module.exports = {
  mA: router.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log('a');
    next();
  }),
  mB: router.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log('b');
    next();
  }),
};
```

## routes/myRoute.js

```
const { mA, mB } = require('../middlewares/myMiddleware');
router.get('/welcome'
  , mA
  ,(req, res) => res.render('welcome'));
router.get('/welcome2'
  , mB
  ,(req, res) => res.render('welcome2'));
module.exports = router;
```

This should work like this
welcome -> log a
welcome2 -> log b

but it works
welcome -> log a, log b
welcome2 -> log a, log b
why?
And how can I fix it? is this bad design?

Comment: Don't use next because it not mandatory

Comment: @Devrajverma Thanks for comment :) But without next(), it doesn't work. pages doesn't display. Maybe middleware cannot pass request to route without next().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `router.use((req, res, next) => {...})` forces a  middleware to be applied to entire router.

Middlewares aren't defined correctly here. As the manual states,

> Middleware functions are functions that have access to the request object (req), the response object (res), and the next middleware function in the application’s request-response cycle. The next middleware function is commonly denoted by a variable named next.

While `mA` and `mB` are router instances that already have middlewares applied to them.

They should be:

```
module.exports = {
  mA: (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('a');
    next();
  },
  mB: (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('b');
    next();
  },
};
```

Comment: Thanks, I just move middleware to app.js! :)

Answer (score 0):

next() is a function exposed by Express framework. Its not part of Nodejs but of Expressjs. as per express documentation
"Middleware functions are functions that have access to the request object (req), the response object (res), and the next function in the application’s request-response cycle. The next function is a function in the Express router which, when invoked, executes the middleware succeeding the current middleware."

Hope this helped you.

Thanks

Comment: But it's expected that next middleware (route handler) is executed here after mA and mB.